# $Ax+By+Cz=D \text { has a solution iff } \gcd(\gcd(A,B),C)\mid D$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I read today that $Ax+By+Cz=D \text { has a solution iff } \gcd(\gcd(A,B),C\mid D$ but I can't find it again, I also can't find any Diophantine equations with 3 variables that doesn't have solutions so I'm starting to suspect that I'm remembering something wrong.

My questions are: Are there Diophantine equations with 3 variables that has no solutions?

Is the statement in the title correct?

Note: $A,B,C,D,x,y,z\in \mathbb Z$ and $ A,B,C\neq0$.

Comment: Note that $\gcd(gcd(A,B),C)=\gcd(A,B,C)$. For a Diophantine equation without a solution, take for instance $2x+2y+2z=5$.

Comment: This is the Euclidean Algorithm, I think.

Comment: All 3-variable Diophantine equations you've found have solutions; what does that have to do with remembering something wrong, when the example you give also does?

Comment: @JoeZ. yeah it's related but I don't see the part in the title...

Comment: Do you already know that $Ax+By=F$ has a solution if and only if $\gcd(A,B)\mid F$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think so, does it scale up to 3 variables?

Comment: Sure, it's basically induction on the number of variables. $Ax+By=\gcd(A,B)$ then $\gcd(A,B)U + CV=\gcd(\gcd(A,B),C)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews well I tried just now and it didn't work, take $A=81, B=57, C=9, D=10$ then $\gcd (A,B,C)=3$ which does not divide $10$ but I just made a program that finds how many solutions a given equation has and it does find solutions...

Comment: That sounds like it works - there shouldn't be a solution. What do you mean, it "doesn't work?"

Comment: The statement of the result should be about *integer* solutions. Did your program produce an integer solution? Programs are not always correct. If it produced an integer solution, you might check by hand whether the claimed solution really is a solution.

Comment: @AndréNicolas yeah you're right, I just checked again and it does find non integer solutions... Pretty embarrassing.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Andre was right, it was an int/float error in the program...

Comment: Computers are not going to help you understand this, I think. $81x+57y+9z=3(27x+19y+3z)$, so if $D$ is not divisible by $3$...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yeah I see. BTW do you know of a proof online of the statement in the title or with one less variable like you mentioned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ax + by = \gcd(a,b)$$

has a solution $(x_0,y_0)$

so write:

$$ax_0 + by_0 = \gcd(a,b)$$

Then,

$$\gcd(a,b)w + cz = \gcd(\gcd(a,b),c)$$

has a solution $(w_0,z_0)$:

$$\gcd(a,b)w_0 + cz_0 = \gcd(\gcd(a,b),c)$$

Substituting for $\gcd(a,b)$ and some algebra, simplifying:

$$a(x_0w_0) + b(y_0w_0) + c(z_0) = \gcd(a,b,c)$$

so the original equation:

$$ax + by + cz = \gcd(a,b,c)$$

has a solution

$$x = x_0 w_0, y = y_0w_0,z = z_0$$

If you want *all* solutions, use $x = x_0 + \frac {b}{\gcd(a,b)}t$, etc

Because of this, the same theorems apply for three variable as for two, regarding linear equations with no solutions.